# prove limit of exponential function without concept of logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, exponential-function, epsilon-delta

The question is, prove that if a real number $x>1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n = \infty$, where $n \in \mathbb N$, without using the logarithmic concept. I came up with a proof, but I'm not so sure about it. So I want to verify if it is correct.

$n \in \mathbb N$, and define a sequence $\{x_n\}=\{x, x^2, x^3, ...\}$.

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is bounded. By the least upper bound property of $\mathbb R$, there exists $c=\sup_n\{x_n\}$. However, since there exists an element $cx \in \{x_n\}$, and $cx>c$, it is a contradiction.

Therefore, $\{x_n\}$ is not bounded. Since it is non-empty and unbounded, for any $M\in \mathbb N$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x^N > M$.

Since $\{x_n\}$ is monotone increasing, for any $M\in \mathbb N$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that if $m > N$, $x^m > M$. Hence $\lim_{n\to \infty} x^n = \infty$.

Is it flawless?

Comment: something missing in your lim . maybe $x^n$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your "least upper bound property of R". 1-1/n is bounded and  monotone increasing, but you won't get the sup_n.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET, $\sup_n \{1-1/n\} = 1$?

Comment: Oh, then sup_n  is just max, not the function giving its n ? but then I don't understand the argument with $c x > c$.

Comment: What values does $x$ take?

Comment: I do not see the  argument of the paragraph that end in $cx\gt c$, contradiction. But it can be done. Let $x=1+t$. There is an $n$ such that $x_n\gt \frac{c}{1+t/2}$. But then $x_{n+1}\gt \frac{1+t}{1+t/2}c\gt c$, contradiction.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Thanks, I edited to $x^n$. And since x > 1, and c is an element of $\{x_n\}$, so cx > c, isn't it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, since there exists an element $cx \in \{xn\}$, and $cx>c$, it is a contradiction.

This is false, and I cannot figure out how you contrived this claim.
$\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$

Instead, since $c = \sup(\{x_n:n\in\nn\}) \ge x > 1$, let $y \in \{x_n:n\in\nn\}$ such that $y>\frac{c}{x}$ since $\frac{c}{x} < c$. Then $xy > c$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I'm kind of new to analysis, so is this comprehension right? Although c is the supremum, c might not be an element of $\{x_n\}$, so I can't say cx is in $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: @Zeta611: Yes. You should always look at simple examples like $\sup(\{0,0.9,0.99,0.999,\cdots\})$.

Comment: Ohh, right. Thank you!

Comment: @Zeta611: Supremum is the best upper bound, so any lower cannot be an upper bound. In this case it means that $\frac{c}{x}$ cannot be an upper bound for your sequence since $c > 0$ and $x > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. Since $x >1$, we have
$x=1+t$ for some $t>0$. Then
$x^n = (1+t)^n = \sum_k \binom{n}{k} t^k \ge 1 + n t$.

Since $1+nt \to \infty$, we have the desired result.

Comment: You probably meant x > 1. And I think this would be a simpler proof, thank you!

Comment: Oops, corrected :-).

Comment: @Zeta611: This method is certainly direct, but it's possible to continue from your partial attempt with just a very short argument, and the technique of using supremums works for a lot of other limits too.